# Win 10 doesn't upgrade to November update or Redstone

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607

I have an one year old ASUS laptop, which originally shipped with Win 8.1. When Windows 10 was released I upgraded without hassle to Windows 10.

Trying to update to November update (Threshold-2) or more recently Redstone just doesn't work.
The upgrade starts and finally Windows is restarting. Then after about 40% oin the upgrade process the upgrade is aborted and Windows is reverted to the previous edition.

In

```
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log
```

the last entry is always:

```
2016-08-09 21:14:39, FatalError [0x090001] PANTHR Exception (code 0xC0000005: ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FFC83C9613C in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\unbcl.dll (+000000000005613C).  Minidump attached (64405 bytes).
```

The last few entries in setupact.log are:

```
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Migrate boot settings
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Reserve space with file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Reserved.FirstApply (576716800)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       AddSpace: add:       576716800, current:       786432000, peak:       786432000
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Reserve space with file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Reserved.SecondApply (157286400)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       AddSpace: add:       157286400, current:       943718400, peak:       943718400
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Install Eula
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Orchestrate OS switch for NewOS with safe OS SafeOS and rollback OS ExternalRollback. DelayedSwitch: 0
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Copy log files from C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther to C:\WINDOWS
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     DISKSPACEQUERY: Post-BOOT operations:
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Upgrade security
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): First boot apply
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Create file/registry on first boot
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Stop suspended services
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): OOBE boot apply
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Refresh localized strings
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Execute provisioning migration
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Gather end install, scope: EVERYTHING
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       AddSpace: add:       314572800, current:       314572800, peak:       314572800
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP       Operation (remaining): Start suspended services
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     DISKSPACEQUERY: Final disk space needed estimate: 943718400 + 314572800 = 1258291200
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     Executing operation: Relocate OS from C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS to C:\
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     DISKSPACETRACK: Available    : 29226127360
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     DISKSPACETRACK: Needed total : 1258291200
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     DISKSPACETRACK: Needed for op: 0
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     Final list of source OS pieces:
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: WINDOWS, Original path: C:\WINDOWS, Current path: C:\WINDOWS (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: PROGRAMS, Original path: C:\Program Files, Current path: C:\Program Files (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: PROGRAMSX86, Original path: C:\Program Files (x86), Current path: C:\Program Files (x86) (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: USERS, Original path: C:\Users, Current path: C:\Users (allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: PROGRAMDATA, Original path: C:\ProgramData, Current path: C:\ProgramData (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: INETPUB, Original path: C:\inetpub, Current path: C:\inetpub (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: SKYDRIVETEMP, Original path: C:\SkyDriveTemp, Current path: C:\SkyDriveTemp (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         Name: RECOVERY, Original path: C:\Recovery, Current path: C:\Recovery (do not allow relocation)
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     No source symblic mappings found
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP     Final list of Windows.old roots:
2016-08-09 15:12:26, Info                  SP         C:\
2016-08-09 15:12:26, FatalError [0x090001] PANTHR Exception (code 0xC0000005: ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FFE2821613C in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\unbcl.dll (+000000000005613C).  Minidump attached (68317 bytes).
```

I tried Windows Update, Media Creation Tool or Win 10 upgrade assistant without any luck.

Norton AV is uninstalled and Windows Defender is used.

So far I did not try a clean, new installation and I would like to avoid this, if possible.

Any hints or suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Complete setuperr.log:

```
2016-08-09 20:58:44, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2016-08-09 20:58:44, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(735): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-09 20:58:44, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(391): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-09 20:58:44, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(236): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-09 20:58:44, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(372): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-09 21:03:13, Error                 SP     Failed to create WIM handle for \\?\Volume{c5ef6f70-8ba0-47fa-9dae-62c3b55abf3d}\Windows Images\Install.wim. Error: 0x80070015[gle=0x00000015]
2016-08-09 21:03:13, Error                 SP     Failed to create WIM handle for \\?\Volume{c5ef6f70-8ba0-47fa-9dae-62c3b55abf3d}\Windows Images\custom.wim. Error: 0x80070015[gle=0x00000015]
2016-08-09 21:03:25, Error                 SP     Failed to create WIM handle for \\?\Volume{c5ef6f70-8ba0-47fa-9dae-62c3b55abf3d}\Windows Images\Install.wim. Error: 0x80070015[gle=0x00000015]
2016-08-09 21:03:25, Error                 SP     Failed to create WIM handle for \\?\Volume{c5ef6f70-8ba0-47fa-9dae-62c3b55abf3d}\Windows Images\custom.wim. Error: 0x80070015[gle=0x00000015]
2016-08-09 21:04:27, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2016-08-09 21:04:36, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "id" attribute is mandatory. void __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadSupportedComponent(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2016-08-09 21:04:51, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #97586# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 640065002d00440045000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-08-09 21:05:29, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #172943# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 640065002d00440045000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-08-09 21:05:41, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2016-08-09 21:07:09, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] Failed to get preferred homegroup with hr=0x80070490
2016-08-09 21:07:12, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: Skipping device 'SWD\PRINTENUM\WSD-0629E6A1-50D6-4C99-8F72-2112EA8AC266.0034' without driver.
2016-08-09 21:07:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: Skipping device 'SWD\PRINTENUM\WSD-AAA2298E-E65E-4116-A2D2-AC28C7D9D7A1.006E' without driver.
2016-08-09 21:07:14, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1, 0
2016-08-09 21:07:21, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}: WSLicensing: Failed to read machine binding, hr=0x80070002
2016-08-09 21:07:21, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}: WSLicensing: Error reading Server Info hr=0x80070490
2016-08-09 21:07:24, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2016-08-09 21:07:24, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2016-08-09 21:14:39, FatalError [0x090001] PANTHR Exception (code 0xC0000005: ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FFC83C9613C in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\unbcl.dll (+000000000005613C).  Minidump attached (64405 bytes).
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the.ISO, mount the.ISO, then ran the setup.exe from the mounted virtual drive?

Comment: didn't try iso yet

Comment: same error when using the mounted iso